# How come my input box's value isn't being returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using twitter bootstrap, I have created a button with an input box beside it.  I'm trying to then access that value in my view using jQuery but for some reason I can't get anything back besides "undefined".  Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
var browserInput = $("#browserInput").val();
console.log(browserInput);
```

Html:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addBrowser">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            Add
            </button>
        </span>
        <input id="browserInput" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: none;" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a value in it? When do you call this code?

Comment: Your input is set to not display. You have no default value in it (you can use `value=''` to set one). You have no context of when the javascript code is executed. Is it fired before the page loads? Or is it tied to some submit button?

Comment: The first time I call it, there isn't any values included and it only "un-hides" the input box.  Then the second time it is called with a value inserted.

Comment: `I can't get anything back besides "undefined"` Meaning `$("#browserInput")` returns empty object

Comment: Got it to work! I was missing the default value setter.  Once that was put in it worked great.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @chadb768 `I was missing the default value setter` How that?

Comment: Apparently I needed to put
    value=""
in the <input> and it worked.

Comment: What... I deleted my answer because that wasn't the case 0_o

Comment: @chadb768 Apparently you are testing it wrongly. `value` property is always set for input type text. You said in your question, undefined was returned, obviously you were calling it on empty object, trying to access element before it was available in the DOM. So could you post an example where you ***have to*** set value attribute? I'd like to see it because it would be quite new for me, in fact

Comment: Here's what it looks like with it working now

    <input id="browserInput" type="text" class="form-control" style="display: none;" value="">

I can't give away much other code because the company I work for would be too happy about it, but to be put vaguely, I'm using Backbone.View.Extend which then has an event specified for when I click my "addBrowser" button I have up there. It then calls this function:

    add_browser: function(e)
        {
            var browserInput = $("#browserInput").val();
            console.log(browserInput);
            $("#browserInput").toggle(300);
        }

Comment: Shit sorry, I can't seem to get the code shading right on here.  But anyway, I wish I had another example where I needed to put value="" in there, but this is the only instance where it happened.  All my other code works just fine without it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your actual code layout, you won't get a value because the DOM isn't loaded at the time you are requesting the value.

You should try to wrap your function in document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var browserInput = $("#browserInput").val();
  console.log(browserInput);
});
```

If you want to have the value on keyup or interaction with the input box, you can also do it like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#browserInput').on('keyup',function() {
  var browserInput = $("#browserInput").val();
  console.log(browserInput);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to undelete my answer because apparently it helped the poster solve his issue...

```
<input id="browserInput" type="text" value="" class="form-control" style="display: none;" />
```

Seems that having the `value=""` in the `<input>` tag made a difference for him.

I wonder if he meant `""` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: I also have no idea why this worked. I haven't had to do value="" in any of my other input boxes, but I guess I can't complain if it works now!